# Problem with Delegate and Event handling

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

After I google so much and I still cant understand how does the delegate and event works.

What I want to achieve is:
Class 1 will be playing animation, when the animation END, it will pass the delegate/event to the Class 2 so that Class 2 will do something on the animation END.

I wonder how can I code the above behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic event implementation...

```
public delegate void Class1AnimationCompletedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public class Class1
{
    public event Class1AnimationCompletedHandler AnimationCompleted;

    private void OnAnimationCompleted(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.AnimationCompleted != null)
        {
            // raises the AnimationCompleted event
            this.AnimationCompleted(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void Animate()
    {
        // do your animation steps here

        this.OnAnimationCompleted(new EventArgs());
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    private Class1 c1;

    public Class2()
    {
        // initialize the class
        c1 = new Class1();

        // attach this.Class1_AnimationCompleted to the AnimationCompleted event;
        c1.AnimationCompleted += new Class1AnimationCompletedHandler(this.Class1_AnimationCompleted);
    }

    private void Class1_AnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do your post-animation stuff here
    }

}
```

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) provides a good quick example on how to create events.  It's targeted for VS 2003, but is still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a Publisher (the class exposing an event) and Subscriber (the class registering an handler to event).

Though, in the scenario you mentioned, can you not call the DoSomething of Class2 directly from within Class1?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two classes. I assume you're talking about instances above.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public event EventHandler Finished;

    public ClassA() {}

    public void Animate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassA instance animating.");
        if (Finished != null)
            Finished(this, null);
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB() {}

    public void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassB instance doing work.");
    }
}
```

Then, if you had a win form you'd have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.Finished += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClassB b = new ClassB();
            b.DoWork();
        };
        a.Animate();
    }
}
```

And the output would be:

```
ClassA instance animating.
ClassB instance doing work.
```

Answer (score 0):

So `Class1` will expose an event, to which `Class2` will attach a delegate. When the animation  ends `Class1` will raise the event. Is that what you need?

```
    class Class1
    {
        public delegate void AnimationEndHandler();
        public event AnimationEndHandler AnimationEnded;

        public void Animation()
        {
            //do the animation
            Console.WriteLine("Animation ended. This is class 1");
            AnimationEnded();
        }
    }

    class Class2
    {
        public Class2(Class1 c1)
        {
            c1.AnimationEnded += new Class1.AnimationEndHandler(DoSomethingOnAnimationEnd);
        }

        public void DoSomethingOnAnimationEnd()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Animation ended. This is class 2");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Class2 c2 = new Class2(c1);

        c1.Animation();
    }
```